# Filter Points Layer by Polygon Layer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, filter, nullreferenceexception

I come from the Java world and go straight to C# and ArcGis 10 (I have to make a simple task for the university). So this means I don't really know much of C# but I can live with it and don't know ArcGis API at all. All I have is an example from the classes. It is about how to filter the cities by coordinates X and Y and a `Buffer`. So we have layers `City`(Point) and `States`(Polygon). My task is to make other functionality, and by functionality I mean method, that takes the name of 1 state and get all the cities from state's area.
In the example code that we have some `ISpatialFilter` that we use with the buffer like this:

```
public List<City> SearchCities(...)
{
    IFeatureClass citiesClass = MyHelper.GetLayer(Layers.CITIES);

    ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = getSpatialFilter(centerX, centerY, distance);

    IFeatureCursor citiesCursor = citiesClass.Search((QueryFilter)spatialFilter, true);
    .....
    .....
}

private static ISpatialFilter getSpatialFilter(double centerX, double centerY, double distance)
{
    IPoint center = getCenter(centerX, centerY);
    IGeometry buffer = getBuffer(distance, center);

    ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
    spatialFilter.Geometry = buffer;
    spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;

    return spatialFilter;
}


private static IGeometry getBuffer(double distance, IPoint center)
{
    return (center as ITopologicalOperator).Buffer(distance);
}

private static IPoint getCenter(double centerX, double centerY)
{
    IPoint center = new Point();
    center.PutCoords(centerX, centerY);
    return center;
}
```

So I decided to reuse some of the code and only change the way the data is filtered. So, I came up with something like this:

```
private IQueryFilter GetQueryFilter(string stateAbbr)
{
    IGeometry stateGeometry = getGeometry(stateAbbr);

    ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
    spatialFilter.Geometry = stateGeometry;
    spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;

    return (QueryFilter)spatialFilter;
}

// TODO fix it
private IGeometry getGeometry(string stateAbbr)
{
    IFeature state = GetStateByAbbr(stateAbbr);

    return (state as ITopologicalOperator).Boundary;
}

private IFeature GetStateByAbbr(string stateAbbr)
{
    IFeatureClass statesClass = MyHelper.GetLayer(Layers.STATES);
    IQueryFilter queryFilter = GetStateQueryFilter(stateAbbr);
    IFeatureCursor stateCursor = statesClass.Search(queryFilter, false);

    return stateCursor.NextFeature();
}

private IQueryFilter GetStateQueryFilter(string stateAbbr)
{
    ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
    spatialFilter.WhereClause = StatesWhereBuilder(stateAbbr);

    return (QueryFilter)spatialFilter;
}

private string StatesWhereBuilder(string stateAbbr)
{
    return (MyHelper.isEmpty(stateAbbr)) ? "" : MyHelper.CreateEqualStatement(StateConst.STATE_ABBR, stateAbbr, true);
}
```

I know it is probably very amusing for some of you, but this is all I came up with :]  The problem is that I get `NullReferenceException` after calling `(state as ITopologicalOperator).Boundary` but the debug shows that `state` is not null. So after the `as` something happens. I might be wrong with the `ITopologicalOperator`. If so, what should I use instead? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Please tell me what do you think about this question (how it is exposed, etc.)

I changed the GetGeometry() method to:

```
private IGeometry getGeometry(string stateAbbr)
{
    IFeature state = GetStateByAbbr(stateAbbr);
    IPolygon statePolygon = state.Shape as IPolygon;

    return (statePolygon as ITopologicalOperator).Boundary;
}
```

and now I don't have NullPointerException, but I don't get any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IToplogicalOperator.Boundary`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Boundary_Property/002m000003v7000000/) returns a polyline if the input geometry is a polygon. You probably don't want that (selecting cities by the boundary/perimeter as opposed to the the interior/area of a state makes no sense), so just return the feature's [`Shape`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Shape_Property/002500000330000000/) or [`ShapeCopy`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ShapeCopy_Property/002500000331000000/).

Also it's good to know the difference between these, and between a recycling and non-recycling cursor.

A recycling cursor reuses internal resources used by the previous row as soon as the next row is accessed (and so should not be used if modifying the row), while a non-recycling cursor does not, at the cost of memory and speed. See the "Recycling" section under [How to use cursors in the geodatabase](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/dotnet/bdb9558a-d78d-446c-a9d8-f35f9eb44a5b.htm) for more info.

`Shape` returns the feature's geometry directly, if you are using a recycling cursor, you have to be sure you don't need that reference for longer than one row iteration if you are using a recycling cursor. `ShapeCopy` creates a clone of the feature's geometry that you can then hold on to (and are responsible for releasing in a timely manner if you don't want to wait for the [GC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to do it when it feels like it).

In this case since you are only accessing one feature, it doesn't matter too much, but I would use a recycling cursor and ShapeCopy. Release the cursor immediately after you've gotten your shape copy, and release the shape copy as soon as you are done querying with it.

Comment: Perfect :) My dummy workaround was to use Buffer(0), which I suppose is something like Shape.